# Who came up with the theory of Krylov Subspaces?

Tags: mathematicians

The well celebrated field of numerical linear algebra is heavily based on Krylov subspace methods. A quick google search on Krylov himself returned the following results:

- Nikolay Krylov (1941-) [Russian mathematician]
- Aleksey Krylov (1863-1945) [Russian engineer and mathematician]
- Nikolay Krylov (1879-1955) [Russian mathematician]

But it seems that none of them have personally been a part of the creation or development of "Krylov Subspace Method" and most definitely not in numerical linear algebra.

> Question: If it is not some "Krylov" who led foundation of the "Krylov subspace methods" then who was/were the mathematician(s) that were part of its invention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was [Aleksey Krylov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleksey_Krylov), see (in Russian):

[De la résolution numérique de l'équation servant à déterminer dans des questions de mécanique appliquée les fréquences de petites oscillations des systèmes matériels](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=im&paperid=5215&option_lang=eng). Bulletin de l'Académie des Sciences de l'Union des Républiques Soviétiques Socialistes. VII série. Classe des sciences mathématiques et naturelles. 1931, Issue 4, Pages 491–539.